# windows dropdown menu pass file name to vb.net program

Tags: vb.net, windows, filenames, regedit

I have a few files that pending on factors may require an alternate-variation to be used. The selection of the right file starts at standard windows directory C:\Drawings in my case, So I know that we can add items to the windows backbround context menu as follows:

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\mymenu]
@="test123"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\mymenu\command]
@="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\NOTEPAD.EXE %1"
```

However (and im not sure even if this is possible) i would like to get the name of the file that was cliked and use it in my vb.net application for example a textbox wich displays that files name.

dose anybody know if i can do this? and how?

Comment: are you asking about how to access the "%1" in your app?  Those are called CommandLineArguments

Comment: Actually Im not quite so sure about regedit topics but as far as my understanding goes %1 returns the file name? and yeah that would be great if i could reuse that name in my vb. net application

Comment: Explorer passes the filename to your app as a command line argument.  There are multiple ways to get them

Comment: It does not pass only the file name, but the entire file's path.

Comment: that dosnt matter vincent a path is easly striped from the actuall file name :)

Comment: Just like I did in my answer. (:

Answer (score 2):

First you'll have to get the command line arguments, which can be done in a few different ways but I prefer to use [**`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim Arguments() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

Then you must check that there's actually an argument to read. The very first argument (index 0) is **always** the path to your application, therefore we must check that it contains at least **two** arguments to be sure that there is also one passed to your app.

```
If Arguments.Length >= 2 Then
```

Finally you just get the path to the file from the second argument, and call [**`IO.Path.GetFileName()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) on that:

```
Dim FilePath As String = Arguments(1) 'Second argument has index 1.
Dim FileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath)
```

If you don't want the file's path at all you can just go ahead and do:

```
Dim FileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(Arguments(1))
```

---

**Full code:**

```
Dim Arguments() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

If Arguments.Length >= 2 Then
    Dim FilePath As String = Arguments(1) 'Second argument has index 1.
    Dim FileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath)

    'Do your stuff here.
End If
```

Comment: there is also `My.Application.CommandLineArgs` which does not include the EXE path as (0).  The NET methods all do, but I think all the VB versions omit it.

Comment: @Plutonix : It's one way out of many :). I like the VB.NET language but I prefer to not use its custom classes/properties/methods. For some reason I like the common .NET stuff better.

Comment: Me too.  My point was that you stress element 0 is the path, that is not the case with all the VB methods

Comment: okay Ive been googeling some more and to clarify what I would like is to have the result (which is displayed ussing the following code) to be passed on to my vb.net application {Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\lalalulu\command]
@="cmd.exe /c msg * \"%1\""}

Comment: @TM80 your app is not mentioned in that reg entry. `cmd` is an OS component. are you trying to get the filename being passed to *another* app (notepad, cmd) ??

Comment: @TM80 : For that it would be better if your VB.NET app opened the cmd instance instead, and just read from it's Standard  Output.

Comment: yeah the whole thing is we have parts drawings which come in assembly variations (3 diffrent sizes) the program we use imports parts ussing a file open dialogue so i am limited to starting with appending regedit windows dropdown menu. the idea being that I rightclick the requierd file and choose one of its variations if requierd the name of the file would be the same except in a diffrent sub directory this would make navigating and maintaining a parts library just a whole lot more simple

Comment: @TM80 : You can still do that via VB. Just pass the file as an argument (via the Windows Drop down menu, aka Context Menu) to your VB application, and let it start the other app of yours via [**`Process.Start(fileName, arguments)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx). The file's path can then just be passed in the arguments.

Comment: Excellent coding @VisualVincent